# git: 'ssh-keygen' is not a git command. See 'git --help'

Tags: windows, git, ssh, mingw, mingw32

I was trying to follow the [instructions on GitHub](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent/) to generate an SSH key so I can push from my laptop to my GitHub account. I'm using Git on Windows 10 with mingw32, and I entered this command in Git Bash (not cmd):

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "your_email@example.com"
```

This failed with `git: 'ssh-keygen' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.`

Why would that be and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure of your `%PATH%` (in a CMD) *before* entering your `git bash` session.

If your `PATH` is correct, then this is what you should see:

```
vonc@voncvb:/mnt/c$ which ssh-keygen
/usr/bin/ssh-keygen
```

For testing, set a simplified `PATH` in your CMD session.

```
set PATH=C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
set GH=C:\Git
set PATH=%GH%\bin;%GH%\usr\bin;%GH%\mingw64\bin;%MAVEN_HOME%\bin;%PATH%
```

Then type `bash`, to enter a bash shell session.
And try there `ssh-keygen`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using command -> `ssh-keygen -o`
This worked for me.
Please refer to the following page for details, under the Git for Windows section.

Link: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Generating-Your-SSH-Public-Key

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34601599)