# Trouble with Git on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, git-bash

*This problem is not related to any git configuration nor repository, it's related with the Program Gith Bash and the OS Windows 10*

It began once I installed and customized Git Bash on my Windows profile, it never appeared the Git icon on the toolbar, which was bothering me.
So I start to go after some ways to fix it. (reinstalling never worked)

In an attempt to erase all customizations I made on Git Bash I deleted everything related to Git from the Windows Registry Editor, which at the time I thought would solve the problem but only made it worse.

Now I can't even start my Git Bash, it's sort of useless, and none of the modifications I made was undone.

When I install Git and try to open the Bash it shows with the visual customizations I made + the following message.

[image: git bash error: permissions dennied]

Comment: Maybe examine/include the contents of `.bashrc` and/or `.bash_profile`, from the `%USERPROFILE%` folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, try to type "bash" in a CMD where you have set up (for testing) a [simplified PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51914281/6309)

```
set PATH=C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
set GH=C:\Git
set PATH=%GH%\bin;%GH%\usr\bin;%GH%\mingw64\bin;%MAVEN_HOME%\bin;%PATH%
```

Then simplify your `.bashrc` in order to check what causes those error messages.

I generally tend to rely on a simple Git installation, by unzipping [`64-bit Git for Windows Portable`](https://git-scm.com/download/win) anywhere I want.